# Should I implement a trait also by value to allow for better performance?

Tags: performance, optimization, rust

Let's say I have the following enums :

```rust
enum SomeEnum {
    V1(i32),
    V2(f32),
    V3(String),
    V4(Vec<i32>),
}
#[derive(Debug)]
enum SomeEnumConversionError {
    OutOfTypeRange,
    StringParse,
    TooManyElements,
}
```

And I want the following trait to work for both values and references of the first enum; So I implement it for the reference to save some time and a few lines of duplicate code (Considering I have to do almost the same for all other variants and the real enum I'm working with has about 30 variants) :

```rust
impl TryFrom<&SomeEnum> for i32 {
    type Error = SomeEnumConversionError;
    fn try_from(value: &SomeEnum) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        match value {
            SomeEnum::V1(v) => Ok(*v),
            SomeEnum::V2(v) => {
                let i = *v as i32;
                if (i as f32) == *v {
                    Ok(i)
                } else {
                    Err(SomeEnumConversionError::OutOfTypeRange)
                }
            }
            SomeEnum::V3(v) => v
                .parse::<i32>()
                .map_err(|_| SomeEnumConversionError::StringParse),
            SomeEnum::V4(v) if v.len() == 1 => Ok(v[0]),
            SomeEnum::V4(v) => Err(SomeEnumConversionError::TooManyElements),
        }
    }
}
impl TryFrom<SomeEnum> for i32 {
    type Error = SomeEnumConversionError;
    fn try_from(value: SomeEnum) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        (&value).try_into()
    }
}
```

Now, if I have the following code as an example usage :

```rust
fn some_func() {
    let a = SomeEnum::V4(vec![4i32]);
    let b: Result<i32, _> = a.try_into();
    println!("{}", b.unwrap());
}
```

The question is, how is this (performance-wise, considering the conversion might be called in a loop) compared to when I implement the trait for both value and reference type (rather than just calling it by reference from value implementation) ?
Does the compiler do some optimization magic here that will eventually make it behave as if the variable `a` has been actually moved to the function implementation calls ?
Or do I need to also implement the whole conversion function for the value type to ensure this ?

If there are better alternatives to the whole plan, I'm all ears.

Comment: In the general sense, a conversion that consumes the input can often take advantage of that by avoiding copies. However I don't see that making an impact here since the output is a simple `i32`, and the inputs are either similarly simple or can't take advantage of ownership. As always though, measure!

Comment: What about the `Vec<i32>` or similar variants ?